# How to set Google Chrome default profile with protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I want to run test with default google chrome profile e.g cache/cookies should be enabled on running tests.

I have tried below mentioned options but this is not working at all.

```
 capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile']
  }

},
```

Answer (score 1):

***The core problem here*** is that Chrome starts a new instance every time it starts.  "new" is defined by a totally separate and independent Chrome that has no idea about your 'personal' profiles.  I don't think it supports that somewhat obvious customer scenario.

**What it CAN do instead** is save your profile data for use in future "new" instances.

See this answer from '**Isaac Lyman**':  [keep protractor browser session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740056/keep-protractor-browser-session-alive)