# Protractor with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, protractor, e2e-testing

My goal is to perform e2e tests on a knockoutJS page (no AngularJS on the page at all).  I started using Protractor for this test.  With `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` and generous use of promises, the spec appears to execute in the correct order, but it looks like no `expect` statements are found.  I get a message `No specs found` even though I have three `it` calls with `expect` statements inside.

Here's my code:

```
var debug = true;

describe('check for highlighting', function() {

  var url = 'http://domain/page.aspx', 
    formLoadedField = 'NameField',
    selectId = 'Action',
    selectValue = 'Change Values Option',
    testValue = 'Some Test Value!!',
    sourceField = 'FromField',
    targetField = 'ToField',
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  log('load the page in the browser.  use promises to keep the flow of the tests accurate');
  browser.get(url)    
    .then( function(){
      log('wait for the form to load (check presence of specific input)');
      browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id(formLoadedField))), 5 * 1000);

      log('change select to specific option in order to show additional content on the page');
      element( by.cssContainingText('#'+selectId+' option', selectValue)).click();    
    })

    .then( function(){
      log('wait for addtional fields to load completely');
      browser.wait( EC.presenceOf(element( by.id(targetField) )), 5 * 1000);
    })

    .then( function(){
      log('test that the additional field is present.');
      it('should have a targetField element', function() {
        expect( EC.presenceOf(element( by.id(targetField) )) ).toBe(true);
      });
    })

    .then( function(){          
      log('update the source field with the test value');
      element( by.id(sourceField) ).sendKeys( testValue );

      log('Test that the targetField has the highlight class.');
      it('targetField should be highlighted when values are different', function() {
        expect( hasClass(element( by.id(targetField) ),'highlight') ).toBe(true);
      });
    })

    .then( function(){
      log('update the target field with the test value.');
      element( by.id(targetField) ).sendKeys( testValue );

      log('Test that the targetField does not have the hightlight class.');
      it('targetField should NOT be highlighted when values are equal', function() {
        expect( hasClass(element( by.id( targetField ) ),'highlight') ).not.toBe(true);
      });
    });

}); 

function log(msg){
    if(debug){
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
PS C:\> protractor conf.js
[09:38:08] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[09:38:08] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
load the page in the browser.  use promises to keep the flow of the tests accurate
Started


No specs found
Finished in 0 seconds
wait for the form to load (check presence of specific input
change select to specific option in order to show additional content on the page
wait for addtional fields to load completely
test that the additional field is present.
update the source field with the test value
Test that the targetField has the highlight class.
update the target field with the test value.
Test that the targetField does not have the hightlight class.
[09:38:13] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:38:13] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

My research indicates that using Protractor is advocated for AngularJS.

- Some advocate using Jasmine instead of Protractor for what I am
  trying (e2e tests on KnockoutJS page).
- Some say that Protractor is
  sufficient for testing KnockoutJS pages, but that you must manage the
  timing of the tests yourself (a key feature of Protractor).
- I tried some code that set ignoreSynchronization to true before the test and
  then back to false afterwards, but that did not give the results I am
  looking for (or I misunderstood the strategy).
- I was able to get the tests to run previously, but due to the asynchronous 
  nature of Protractor, the tests were not in sync with the changes to the 
  page, so the testing was irrelevant.

I look forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that you need to use `beforeEach()` and `it()` blocks in order for the promises to be put on the [Protractor/WebDriverJS Control Flow](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/control-flow) and jasmine to discover your tests:

```
var debug = true;

describe('check for highlighting', function() {

  var url = 'http://domain/page.aspx', 
    formLoadedField = 'NameField',
    selectId = 'Action',
    selectValue = 'Change Values Option',
    testValue = 'Some Test Value!!',
    sourceField = 'FromField',
    targetField = 'ToField',
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;  // TODO: move to onPrepare

    log('load the page in the browser.  use promises to keep the flow of the tests accurate');
    browser.get(url).then( function(){
      log('wait for the form to load (check presence of specific input)');
      browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id(formLoadedField))), 5 * 1000);
      log('change select to specific option in order to show additional content on the page');
      element( by.cssContainingText('#'+selectId+' option', selectValue)).click();    
    }).then( function(){
      log('wait for addtional fields to load completely');
      browser.wait( EC.presenceOf(element( by.id(targetField) )), 5 * 1000);
    });
  });

  it('should have a targetField element', function() {
    expect( EC.presenceOf(element( by.id(targetField) )) ).toBe(true);
  });

  // ...
});
```

---

> Some advocate using Jasmine instead of Protractor for what I am trying (e2e tests on KnockoutJS page).

Jasmine and Protractor are not alternatives. Jasmine is just a [testing framework](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/frameworks) that Protractor can use (and uses by default). You can also use other testing frameworks in place of Jasmine, like `CucumberJS`.

> Some say that Protractor is sufficient for testing KnockoutJS pages, but that you must manage the timing of the tests yourself (a key feature of Protractor).

You can use Protractor to test any web application out there. It's just that Protractor really shines with it's built-in sync and specific locators when used to test an AngularJS application. But, you can (I would even say should) use it to test the KnockoutJS app you've got - you just have to turn the sync off via the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`. Protractor is still a very good wrapper around WebDriverJS and has a convenient and feature-rich API.

Comment: @alec.xe Thank you for the input and direction.  Question:  with the code changes you put in place, each test will require a new browser session.  Can this be configured so a sequence of tests are completed as the page changes values?

Comment: @Bill well, it is a common pattern to start each test with a clean browser session and navigate inside the `beforeEach` or `beforeAll`..please see more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740056/keep-protractor-browser-session-alive..thanks.