# I have a use case where i need to keep the protractor session as well as the browser instance alive after the tests end. Is there a way to do so?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver

Similar to selenium using java, the session and the browser driver instance doesn't end on its own till user calls `driver.quit()`, however in protractor, the session as well as the browser instance ends on its own once all tests are complete.

I have a use case where i want to keep the protractor session as well as the browser instance alive after the tests end. does anyone have any idea ? please help

I have tried searching about this in many places however there is no concrete information. A similar question is using this issue : [keep protractor browser session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740056/keep-protractor-browser-session-alive)

this just keeps the browser open, but ends the protraactor test instance or session. I want to have both the protractor as well as browser instance running after the tests end.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your comment I have changed my answer. In this version the session will stay open until the user enters the word "STOP" in the URL bar and presses enter.

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: "protractor.js",
    onComplete : async function () {

        //Manually wait for 60 minutes or until a user enters the words STOP in the searchbar
        await browser.wait(
           protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains("STOP"), 
           60*60*1000, 
           "Waiting until manual extraction complete or STOP entered in url"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but that is a hard coded way to keep the session running. I am working on an internal toolset and the use case is such that it needs certain custom libraries to be injected to extract certain information out of an app at the end. This task has to be completely manual but should be on the same browser and protractor instance which ran the automated tests.

Comment: @Sid ok I proposed another option that may suit the manual nature of your task. If not let me know :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @DublinDev, but this isn't solving the problem as i wanted to initiate certain process to inject a script and listen to browser events on console side upon session start. Probably its a limitation on protractor side. I have been winding over this since so many days but haven't been able to reach to a viable solution.